# Injecting a class into another class

Tags: php, dependency-injection, laravel-5

I have a class **InjectedClass** with a method **someMethod**. The class takes three params. I need the output of the method in another class, **Myclass**. Basicly, i need to pass the same three params trough a constructor in **Myclass**, to the injected class for it do return some data.

The problem is i get an error stating, that the forth parameter (the injected class) in Myclass constructor is expected to be an instance of injectedClass, but it is empty! See Example.

I think the problem is that Injected class is being initialized without params, hence does not initialize and is therefore, empty. Also, i get more or less the same result if i try to inject the class directly into **myfunction** method. How do i solve this mess?

```
class Myclass {

    private $var1;
    private $var2;
    private $var3;
    private $injectedclass;

    public function __construct($var1, $var2, $var3, InjectedClass $injectedclass)
    {
        $this->var1 = $var1;
        $this->var2 = $var2;
        $this->var3 = $var3;
        $this->injectedclass = $injectedclass;
    }

    public function myfunction()
    {
        return $this->injectedclass($this->var1, $this->var2, $this->var3)->someMethod();
    }
}

class InjectedClass {

    private $var1;
    private $var2;
    private $var3;

    public function __construct($var1, $var2, $var3)
    {
        $this->var1 = $var1;
        $this->var2 = $var2;
        $this->var3 = $var3;
    }

    public function someMethod()
    {
        // do stuff
    }
}
```

Comment: how are you calling `Myclass` ?

Comment: $myclass = new Myclass($var1, $var2, $var3);

Answer (score 0):

MyClass needs only 1 parameter in the construct - InjectedClass instansce, which is ready to work. I.e.

```
$injected = new Injected($var1, $var2, $var);

$my = new MyClass($injected);

$my->myfunction(); // will work correctly now
```

Answer (score 0):

I would rethink how you are trying to use dependency injection. The simplest method off the top of my head would be to create setters within the InjectedClass and set them when you are setting the class variable in the construct. Something like:

```
class Myclass {

    private $var1;
    private $var2;
    private $var3;
    private $injectedclass;

    public function __construct($var1, $var2, $var3, InjectedClass $injectedclass)
    {
        $this->var1 = $var1;
        $this->var2 = $var2;
        $this->var3 = $var3;
        $this->injectedclass = $injectedclass;
        $this->injectedclass->setParams($this->var1, $this->var2, $this->var3);
    }

    public function myfunction()
    {
        return $this->injectedclass($this->var1, $this->var2, $this->var3)->someMethod();
    }
}

class InjectedClass {

    private $var1;
    private $var2;
    private $var3;

    public function setParams($var1, $var2, $var3) {
        $this->var1 = $var1;
        $this->var2 = $var2;
        $this->var3 = $var3;
    }

    public function someMethod()
    {
        // do stuff
    }
}
```

Of course you could clean this up a bit, but by doing the injection this way you should be able to avoid the issue you are facing.

Answer (score 0):

Everything depends what you want to achieve, but basically in

```
public function myfunction()
{
   return $this->injectedclass($this->var1, $this->var2, $this->var3)->someMethod();
}
```

you don't need to pass those parameters because `$this->injectedclass` is already object that has already initialized its properties. So the code should look like this:

```
class Myclass {

    private $var1;
    private $var2;
    private $var3;
    private $injectedclass;

    public function __construct($var1, $var2, $var3, InjectedClass $injectedclass)
    {
        $this->var1 = $var1;
        $this->var2 = $var2;
        $this->var3 = $var3;
        $this->injectedclass = $injectedclass;
    }

    public function myfunction()
    {
        return $this->injectedclass->someMethod();
    }
}

class InjectedClass {

    private $var1;
    private $var2;
    private $var3;

    public function __construct($var1, $var2, $var3)
    {
        $this->var1 = $var1;
        $this->var2 = $var2;
        $this->var3 = $var3;
    }

    public function someMethod()
    {
        // do stuff
        echo $this->var1.' '.$this->var2.' '.$this->var3."<br />";
    }
}

$m = new Myclass(1,2,3, new InjectedClass(1,2,3));
$m->myFunction();
```

However as you see when you create `Myclass` instance you need to pass arguments `1,2,3` to both `Myclass` and `InjectedClass` and if those values are the same this might be not very convenient.

So you can change your code into:

```
class Myclass {

    private $var1;
    private $var2;
    private $var3;
    private $injectedclass;

    public function __construct($var1, $var2, $var3, InjectedClass $injectedclass)
    {
        $this->var1 = $var1;
        $this->var2 = $var2;
        $this->var3 = $var3;
        $this->injectedclass = $injectedclass;
        $this->injectedclass->setParams($var1, $var2, $var3);
    }

    public function myfunction()
    {
        return $this->injectedclass->someMethod();
    }
}

class InjectedClass {

    private $var1;
    private $var2;
    private $var3;

    public function setParams($var1, $var2, $var3)
    {
        $this->var1 = $var1;
        $this->var2 = $var2;
        $this->var3 = $var3;
    }

    public function someMethod()
    {
        // do stuff
        echo $this->var1.' '.$this->var2.' '.$this->var3."<br />";
    }
}

$m = new Myclass(1,2,3, new InjectedClass());
$m->myFunction();
```

so you pass arguments only to `Myclass` and it sets arguments to `InjectedClass`. But this method causes that even if you create object of `InjectedClass`  class you will need to run `setParams` method also to set parameters so it's not the best solution.

The better would be:

```
class Myclass {

    private $var1;
    private $var2;
    private $var3;
    private $injectedclass;

    public function __construct(InjectedClass $injectedclass)
    {
        $this->injectedclass = $injectedclass;
        list ($this->var1, $this->var2, $this->var3) = $this->injectedclass->getParams();
    }

    public function myfunction()
    {
        return $this->injectedclass->someMethod();
    }
}

class InjectedClass {

    private $var1;
    private $var2;
    private $var3;

    public function __construct($var1, $var2, $var3)
    {
        $this->var1 = $var1;
        $this->var2 = $var2;
        $this->var3 = $var3;
    }

    public function getParams() {
        return array ($this->var1, $this->var2, $this->var3);
    }

    public function someMethod()
    {
        // do stuff
        echo $this->var1.' '.$this->var2.' '.$this->var3."<br />";
    }
}

$m = new Myclass(new InjectedClass(1,2,3));
$m->myFunction();
```

where object of `InjectedClass` may return those parameters to object of `Myclass`.